# Parssing web.xml throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'am using **Spring MVC (version 4.1.1.RELEASE)** for my Web Application that uses Services developed in an other Maven Module using **Spring (version 2.0.4)**

Parent pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.bdoci.bdocinteractive.tablet</groupId>
<artifactId>bdoci-tablet</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>


<modules>
    <module>bdoci-tablet-web</module>
    <module>bdoci-services</module>
</modules>
```

Services module pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<organization>
    <name>Business Document</name>
</organization>

<parent>
    <artifactId>bdoci-tablet</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.bdoci.bdocinteractive.tablet</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>


<groupId>com.bdoc.bdocinteractive</groupId>
<artifactId>bdoci-services</artifactId>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<version>${parent.version}</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>bdocwebinteractive</artifactId>
        <version>5.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
        <artifactId>acegi-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
        <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlcleaner</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>propertyset</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensymphony.quartz</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.samba.jcifs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>oscore</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>osworkflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>bdocWebDavRepository</id>
        <name>Bdoc WebDav Maven 2 repository</name>
        <url>https://bdocument.drive.cloudforge.com/projects/BdocDesign2008/m2/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>XWiki</id>
        <name>XWiki Maven 2 repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.xwiki.org/externals</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>JBOSS</id>
        <name>JBoss Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Atlassian</id>
        <name>Atlassian Repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Maven Central</id>
        <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Java.net</id>
        <name>Java .net Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>itextpdf.com</id>
        <name>Maven Repository for iText</name>
        <url>http://maven.itextpdf.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <id>bdocWebDavRepository</id>
        <name>Bdoc WebDav Maven 2 repository</name>
        <url>https://bdocument.drive.cloudforge.com/projects/BdocDesign2008/m2/repository
        </url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludePackageNames>org.apache.*</excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

web application module pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>bdoci-tablet-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.bdoci.bdocinteractive.tablet</groupId>
    <artifactId>bdoci-tablet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>2.4.4</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bdoc.bdocinteractive</groupId>
        <artifactId>bdoci-services</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Dependency Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Bdoci Tablet</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/com/bdoc/bdocinteractive/config/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>bdoci-tablet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>bdoci-tablet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tablet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and Dispatcher Servlet config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bdoci.tablet.controller"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

When starting Tomcat I am getting the following stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:81)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1114)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:313)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:329)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:265)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:235)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1763)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'am not sure if the problem is releated to Spring different version. If it is, how can I resolve this problem?

PS: I can't change Spring Version in the services Module.

Comment: As you already stated don't mix spring versions. Explicitly define the version and framework parts you want to use in your pom.xml (and maybe exclude the spring dependency of the service part). However beware that you might run into issues as 2.0 is pretty old...

Comment: please post your project structure and relevant classpath / buildpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change the Spring version of the service module, you either have to use that version for the entire application, or isolate the service module.

One way to achieve the isolation would be to create a dedicated webapp for the service module, with a remote callable API; then your client webapp can use that API to interact with the service module.

Each webapp has its own classpath, so they could have different versions of Spring.